# Regarding Ui Gradient effect in blackberry

Tags: blackberry

I am trying to have a gradient effect in a horizontalFieldManager through a function. then I am trying to place some controls on top of it.
here is my code

```
 static public void drawVerticalGradientRoundRect(Graphics g, int x, int y, int w, int h, int arc, int color1,
        int color2) {
    /*--3------4-
    2           5
    |          |
    1          6
    |          |
    |          |
    12         7
    |11--10----9--8
     */
    int xPts[] = {x, x, x + arc, x + w - arc, x + w, x + w, x + w, x + w, x + w - arc, x + arc, x, x};
    int yPts[] = {y + arc, y, y, y, y, y + arc, y + h - arc, y + h, y + h, y + h, y + h, y + h - arc};
    int color[] = {color1, color1, color1, color1, color1, color1, color2, color2, color2, color2, color2, color2};
    byte start = Graphics.CURVEDPATH_QUADRATIC_BEZIER_CONTROL_POINT;
    byte end = Graphics.CURVEDPATH_END_POINT;
    byte endPts[] = {end, start, end, end, start, end, end, start, end, end, start, end};
    g.drawShadedFilledPath(xPts, yPts, endPts, color, null);
```

but by using this code every thing else on that place is not visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because this gradient function will create a round rectangle which comes on top of all the other contro u have place at that place. 
try using

```
  super.paint(g);
```

just after the statement from where you are callng this function
Hope it will work..